# Unable to delete a symbol from symbol collection in annotation feature class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, arccatalog, annotation

I am trying to delete a symbol in the Symbol Collection for an Annotation FeatureClass in ArcCatalog.  From what I can tell, there is always one symbol for an annotation featureclass, which should be (0) Default.

In this instance I want to keep that (0)Default and delete (1)Default_12.  Unfortunately when that symbol is selected, delete is grayed out.  It is not grayed out on (0)Default though.

When viewing the attribute table, every record points to (0)Default in both the AnnotationClassID and SymbolID fields.

Is there some method I can use to delete this?

[image]

Comment: Check that the feature dataset, if there is one, or the feature itself are not locked. It would be best to avoid all locks but how you handle them varies by the type of database your are using. Is this a file geodb?

Comment: It is in a feature dataset inside a File Geodatabase.  If it were a lock problem I'm assuming it wouldn't allow me to delete (0) Default but it does allow that.  Typically the (0) Default is not able to be deleted.